# Can System.Timers.Timer elapsed event if previous event still working?

Tags: c#, timer

Can System.Timers.Timer elapsed event if previous event still working?

For example, i set `Interval` 100 ms, but code in handler works 200 ms.

```
 _taskTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
 _taskTimer.Interval = 100;
 _taskTimer.Elapsed += _taskTimer_Elapsed;

void _taskTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
        Work(); // works 200 ms.
}
```

Is timer "wait" while `Work()` method ends? Or execute a new one?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.Timers.Timer`(Multi Threaded Timer)  is multithreaded timer. that means it executes it elapse event on multiple thread and that means it don't wait for previous elapse event.

if you want to wait for previous elapse event to complete that you can use `System.Windows.Timer` (Single Threaded Timer) - this is single threaded timer will execute event on single thread only(UI thread) which created timer.

You can read more about this here : [Timers](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Timers) written by Joe Albahari

Answer (score 2):

Internally system.timers.timer also uses system.threading.timers, so the execution process continues even after elapsed fires new execution.

Have a look at the source code of System.Timers.Timer: [Timers.Cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/timers/system/timers/Timer.cs)

Answer (score 1):

It will Continue Executing on different thread

For reference you can visit [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) page